# What is the meaning of "wild pointer" in C?

Tags: c, pointers

Can anybody tell me, the meaning of wild pointer in C, how to obtain it and is this available in C++?

Comment: Wild pointers like to trash the place.

Comment: that's not wild it's livid...

Comment: One which still runs around poking at random 3 months later while no one can get it to quiet down.

Answer (score 53):

The standard does not define or use the term "wild".  I'd be careful "correcting" other people's opinions about what it means, and I'd especially avoid quoting random non-normative internet junk to support my position.

To me, it would mean a pointer that neither refers to a legitimate object, nor is NULL.  Possible sources of these types of pointer values might include uninitialized pointer objects, objects that have ceased to exist, computed pointer values, improperly aligned pointer values, accidental corruption of the pointer itself, or what it pointed to, etc.

```
int main(void)
{

   int *p;  // uninitialized and non-static;  value undefined
   { 
      int i1; 
      p = &i1;  // valid 
   }            // i1 no longer exists;  p now invalid    

   p = (int*)0xABCDEF01;  // very likely not the address of a real object

   { 
      int i2;  
      p = (int*)(((char*)&i2) + 1);  // p very likely to not be aligned for int access
   }

   {
      char *oops = (char*)&p;  
      oops[0] = 'f';  oops[1] = 35;  // p was clobbered
   }
}
```

and so on, and so forth.  There are all kinds of ways to get an invalid pointer value in C.   My favourite has got to be the guy who tried to "save" his objects by writing their addresses to a file.  Strangely, when he read back those pointer values during a different run of the program, they didn't point to his objects any more.  Fancy, that.

But that's just what wild means to me.  Since it's not a normative term, it means whatever the person who spoke or wrote it meant it to mean.  Ask him or her.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the the term is imprecise and giving 4 possible reasons.

Answer (score 12):

A wild pointer in C is a pointer that has not been initialised prior to its first use.
From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wild_pointer):

> Wild pointers are created by omitting
>   necessary initialization prior to
>   first use. Thus, strictly speaking,
>   every pointer in programming languages
>   which do not enforce initialization
>   begins as a wild pointer.
>
> This most often occurs due to jumping
>   over the initialization, not by
>   omitting it. Most compilers are able
>   to warn about this.

eg

```
int f(int i)
{
    char* dp;    //dp is a wild pointer
    ...
}
```

Comment: The term is also used for a pointer which _had_ been initialized, but which becomes a wildiesis dead by now. see Naveen's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583656/2583678#2583678

Comment: @Magnus - Thanks for the edit!

@sbi - I have usually heard pointers in the state you described being called "dangling pointers", but you are correct that they are effectively in the same state as a "wild pointer".

Comment: not quite the same - in many systems with dynamic memory, the data a dangling pointer points at will appear to be valid until it is reused, whereas a wild one will point to garbage.

Answer (score 5):

It is not s standard term. It is normally used to refer to the pointers pointing to invalid memory location.
`int *p;
*p = 0; //P is a wild pointer`

Or

```
int *p = NULL;
{
  int a;
  p = &a; // as soon as 'a' goes out of scope,'p' is pointing to invalid location
}

*p = 0;
```

Comment: When the location that pointer is pointing to goes out of scope (or is freed), it becomes dangling pointer, not wild. Wild pointer is one that is not initialized.

Comment: @Technowise: I'd disagree. I've heard these two terms used interchangeably.

Answer (score 3):

To get a wild (aka dangling) pointer you:

- Create an object
- Create a pointer to that object
- Delete the object
- Forget to set the pointer to null

The pointer is now classed as "wild" as it's pointing to an arbitrary piece of memory and using it in this state could cause problems with your program.

Comment: I think you have to call them **Dangling pointers**, the *wild* ones are the unitialized ones

Comment: +1 for mentioning the term "dangling pointer". I suspect though that a dangling pointer's not a wild pointer, as Eineiki says.

Comment: The standard does not define "wild" or "dangling", so these corrections are dubious at best.  The standard uses the terms "valid" and "invalid".

Comment: @sbi: only at block scope (ie, automatic storage duration).  Put that definition at file scope, and it is required to be initialized to NULL.

Answer (score 2):

A pointer which is not initialized with any address is called as a wild pointer. It may contain any garbage address, so dereferencing a wild pointer is dangerous

Answer (score 2):

A wild pointer is any pointer that is used (particularly as an L_value {ie (*pointer) = x } ) while having a value that is either not correct or no longer correct.  It could also be used to describe the using of memory that is not defined as a pointer as a pointer (possibly by having followed a wild pointer or by using outdated structure definitions).

There's no official definition.  It's just words that we use when referring to certain pointer errors or the results of those errors.

Answer (score 1):

[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer)

It's a pointer to either uninitialized object or an object with a bad state. using this pointer will cause trouble. the wiki is a good source of explanation.

Comment: If an object violates its invariants, it can also be said to bein a bad state, but a pointer to it isn't a wild pointer. So that definition is somewhat wrong.

Comment: It depends what is the nature of the bad state. But I see your point, I have referred to the wiki page for the exact definition.

Comment: Note that the language requires that access through an lvalue of type unsigned char can always be used to read or write to an object, even if it is in a bad state when interpreted as its declared type.

Answer (score 1):

Wild pointer is a pointer that doesn’t point to either a valid object (of the indicated type, if applicable), or to a distinguished null value, if applicable.

Read more about [Wild Pointer](http://clinuxpro.com/wild-pointer) here

Answer (score 0):

Wild pointer is a pointer which declaration is present but it has not been defined yet.Means we have declare  a pointer -
data_type *ptr; //but not  define which address it is containing 
*ptr=100//wild pointer does not point to any valid address.so we will get ERROR
printf("ptr:%d",ptr);//we will get:0(in gcc compiler)

Answer (score -1):

a ponter which not have locating any data type varable that varable is call the wild pointer

Answer (score -1):

Uninitialized pointer is called Wild Pointer.
Suppose if you try

int *p; //pointing to any random or unknown location.
  *p= 16; /*Some unknown memory location is being corrupted.This should never be done.*/

This can create a great threat to your program. B'Coz because they point to some arbitrary memory location and changing the content of that location may cause a program to crash or behave badly.

Comment: This doesn't add anything new that the existing answers don't have.