# C++ object declaration confusion?

Tags: c++, object, declaration, new-operator

I'm trying to implement a BST in C++, and I came across these two ways of creating a node:

```
node* z = new node();
z->key = d;
z->left = NULL;
z->right = NULL;
```

and then this:

```
node* y = NULL;
node* x = root;
node* parent = NULL;
```

What is the difference in calling the new operator or not?

**EDIT**

so for example, whats the difference between:

```
node* q = new node();
```

and

```
node* q;
```

and why would you choose one way or the other? Is there an advantage for one way or the other?

Comment: `NULL` means it doesn't point to any location, and I think `root` is just another node that is created with `node* root = new node();`

Comment: well I guess my question is, is there a difference in declaring a node like this: `node* q = new node();` and `node* q;`

Comment: Sure, one initializes `q` with a value, the other doesn't and results in a [*wild pointer*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583656/what-is-the-meaning-of-wild-pointer-in-c)

Comment: `node *q;` doesn't have a valid reference to an object `node`

Comment: BTW if you are using C++11 or newer please use `nullptr` and not `NULL`

Comment: And to expand on the comment by @NathanOliver, if you're using an earlier version of C++, then it's recommended to use `0` instead of `NULL`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks I'll keep that in mind, but whats the reason for that?

Comment: @ocean800 The reason is `int a = NULL;` will compile while `int a = nullptr;` will not.  See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816385/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-nullptr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question in the comment, yes there is a difference.

When you do `node* q = new node()` you declare a pointer to a `node` object, and then at runtime dynamically allocate memory enough for one `node` object, and calls the default constructor (alternatively, value initializes the object, it depends on the class/struct), and finally you assign the pointer to the newly allocated object to `q`.

When you do `node* q;` you just declare a pointer to a `node` object, and that's it. What the pointer will be pointing to depends on *where* you declare the pointer: If you declare it as a global variable, it is initialized to zero, and becomes a null pointer; If you declare it as a local variable its value is indeterminate, and will in reality seem to be random. Neither is a valid pointer, and dereferencing it will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). There is also a third alternative, and that's where you declare `node* q;` as a member variable in a `class` or `struct`, then the initial value depend on how the class/structure is created and initialized (for example if the structure is value initialized, if there's a constructor that initializes it, etc.).

Comment: Ah.. I see. So unless I use `new node()`, a new node isn't actually being created. Only a reference to a node will be created.

Comment: @ocean800 That's correct, almost... The correct phrase is a *pointer* to a node. A *reference* in C++ is something else, similar to a pointer, but still different.

Comment: If i have `node* q` and then `q->key=2`.Is that valid?

Comment: @gauravsehgal Not unless you initialize `q` in between, i.e. make it point to a valid`node` object.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks for the help that makes a lot more sense!! :)

Comment: @gauravsehgal Because using a uninitialized pointer is **UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR**.  That means it could work, it could not work, it could give you a million dollars, anything.  See Joachim's link at then end of his answer.

Comment: Thanks.that made sense.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure (Someone correct me if i'm wrong), using the new operator allocates dynamic memory for that variable. The variables will most likely already have some garbage value assigned to them that gets overridden when you assign a new value to them. Whereas assigning it NULL just assigns it whatever the NULL value is (probably 0000000).