# Why does -1 become -842150451 in C++?

Tags: c++

```
struct myclass {
    int id;
    myclass(): id(-1){};
};

myclass *a;
cout >> a->id;
```

This above is a demonstration of my long program. The output should be -1. But I do not know why the output becomes -842150451.

Comment: With `a->blubb` you are dereferencing an invalid pointer value which is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Swordfish Please, answer in the answer section or not at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have **Undefined Behavior**!

You create a `myclass` pointer, but never point it to anything. And then you try to dereference the [dangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer) or [wild pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2583656/2602718).

Try this instead to get the -1 you're expecting:

```
myclass a;
std::cout << a.id;
```