# malloc() fails to allocate memory inside a function in C

Tags: c, pointers

I want to allocate memory dynamically inside a function. The function is named `func_1` and is declared as follows:

`int func_1(int **destination);`

Here `destination` is a pointer to a pointer. This pointer contains the address of the pointer to which I want to allocate memory dynamically inside the function.

The function `func_1` has the following code:

```
void func_1(int **destination)
{
   *destination = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
   for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
   {
      *destination[i] = i;             //segmentation fault comes HERE
   }    
}
```

Below is my `main()` function:

```
int main()
{
   int *pointer;
   func_1(&pointer);
   return 0;
}
```

When I try to run this program, I get a segmentation fault (SIGSEGV) error. I used GDB to locate the source of this fault, and it turned out that the line inside the for loop is the culprit for this error.

Please note that I wish to retain the values I have assigned to the dynamically allocated memory inside the function, once the function exits, and that's the reason due to which I have passed the address of the pointer to which I want to allocate memory dynamically.

I want to know:

- Why am I getting this error ?
- How can this be fixed ?

Thanks for help !

Comment: You forget to `free()` the heap object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[]` (array subscripting) operator has precedence 2

`*` (dereference) operator has precedence 3

In your code `*destination[i]` means the same as `*(destination[i])`. This value is uninitialized and it leads to segmentation fault.

If you will use explicit priority of operation `(*destination)[i]` you will get the expected result.

```
void func_1(int **destination)
{
   *destination = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
   for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
   {
      (*destination)[i] = i;             //no segmentation fault
   }    
}
```

you can read more about precedence [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B)

Full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void func_1(int **destination)
{
   *destination = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
   for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
   {
      (*destination)[i] = i;             
   }
}

int main()
{
   int *pointer;
   func_1(&pointer);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Applying this solution does eliminate the segmentation fault error.

Answer (score 0):

> Why am I getting this error ?

You are overwriting the `destination` pointer instead of assigning the value returned by `malloc` to the pointer *pointed to by* the `destination` pointer.

- Instead of `*destination = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 10)` you should type `**destination = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10)`.
- Instead of `*destination[i] = i` you should type `(**destination)[i] = i`.

---

In C, the array subscript operator `[]` has a higher precedence than the indirection operator `*`. In addition to that, the former is *left-to-right associative*, while the latter is *right-to-left associative*.

In your case this means that you need to type `(**destination)[i] = i;` instead of `**destination[i] = i`, because otherwise the `[i]` will be evaluated before the `**` and you end up indirecting a [wild pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583656/what-is-the-meaning-of-wild-pointer-in-c) (which will cause a segmentation fault extremely likely in the general and absolutely certainly in this case, since you are referencing a null pointer when `i == 0`).

---

> How can this be fixed ?

The "just make it work" fix is the one I presented above.

**However, that does not address the fundamental issue with your code, which is that it is *unnecessarily complicated***. Using a pointer to a pointer is very error-prone and should be avoided. Indeed, there is no need to use one at all in this case.

The following does exactly what you want without all the unnecessary complexity:

```
int* func_1()
{
   int* destination = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
   {
      destination[i] = i;
   }
   return destination;
}
```

```
int main()
{
   int* pointer = func_1();
   free(pointer);
   return 0;
}
```

---

> Please note that I wish to retain the values I have assigned to the dynamically allocated memory inside the function, once the function exits, and that's the reason due to which I have passed the address of the pointer to which I want to allocate memory dynamically.

As I demonstrated above, there is no reason to pass a pointer to the pointer to the function. Memory allocated with `malloc` is yours to use forever , you just need to keep track of it and release it with a call to `free` when you no longer need it. How you keep track of the memory doesn't matter - simply returning a pointer is enough in this case. Modifying `pointer` inside `func_1` rather than catching the function's return value provides no additional benefit and only serves to make the code more complicated than it needs to be.

---

I get the impression that you are somewhat confused about pointers, so I recommend that you revise the subject. Here is a quite clear explanation regarding pointers that also covers pointers to pointeres (and pointers to pointers to pointers): [How do pointers work in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/897414/10749705)

---

Read more:

- [Operator Precedence and Associativity in C](https://overiq.com/c-programming-101/operator-precedence-and-associativity-in-c/)
- [What is a segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346806/what-is-a-segmentation-fault)